# Copy data and data Structures from one OPC Server to another

Tags: eclipse, opc-ua, opc, milo, kura

Is there any way to copy all structure from one OPCUA Server to another Server.
I am trying to create a copy of all nodes from one OPCUA Server to Local Simulation OPC Server.

This is to create a copy of OPCServer in remote to have a copy locally so that the testing and everything is ease.

We have complex structure as well they are as: "DictionaryFragment"
Is there anyway to do it, or is there any tools to import and export.

Answer (score 1):

If both servers understand the structure type, then it is possible. Otherwise it will be rather complicated and you will have to divert to copying as string or something else.

So, best is to make sure that the Local Simulation Server is initialised with the same information models that define the types as the actual server.

Comment: Thanks for the response, no both server doesn't understand each other, Rather local server might be just simple Server with Milo. 
We don't have information on how the remote server model is created.

Comment: We just want to have same model and structure in local just to make testing easier.